# Describing the range of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I came across a question that states the following:

Describe the range of the following function

$g(z) = z^2$ for $z$ in the first quadrant, $\mathrm{Re}\ z \geq 0, \mathrm{Im}\ z \geq 0$

From the question, $w = g(z) = z^2 =(x^2 - y^2) + 2xyi$

if $z = x + yi$, then from the question we can say that $x \geq 0$, and $y \geq 0$.

Doesn't this then mean that  $\mathrm{Re}\ w \geq 0$ since $\mathrm{Re}\ w = (x^2 - y^2)$, and $\mathrm{Im}\ w \geq 0$ since $\mathrm{Im}\ w = 2xy$?

The answer to the question only states that $\mathrm{Im}\ w \geq 0$. Why doesn't it mention the real part?

Comment: I suggest you use polar form of  complex number to establish the range.

Comment: @dxiv my bad, typo. thanks

Comment: @MatthewH. what do you mean specifically?

Comment: @Kalcifer "*Doesn't this then mean that  $\mathrm{Re}\ w \geq 0$ since $\mathrm{Re}\ w = (x^2 - y^2)$*" $\;-\;$ No, that does not follow. Why would you think that $\,x^2 - y^2 \geq 0\,$?

Comment: Take $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r\in[0,\infty)$ and $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$